# objectify v5 query filter by a property in an embedded Class

Tags: java, google-app-engine, backend, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

in my backend application, I have an Entity PositionAugmented

```
@Entity 
public class PositionAugmented {

@Id
Long id;
@Index
Position position;
@Index
String username;
...
}
```

where Position's member variables are

```
public class Position{

Date time;
double latitude;
double longitude;
@Index
public Address address;
...
}
```

and Address is composed by

```
public class Address{

@Index public String city;
...
}
```

using objectify, i need to find all PositionAugmented instances belong to a particular city.
The actual query i am using is the following:

```
public List<PositionAugmented> getPositionAugmentedsByCity(String aCity){
    Query query = ofy().load().type(PositionAugmented.class).
                   filter("position.address.city=", aCity);
    return query.list();
}
```

unfortunately this returns me an empty list.
I tried this query after seeing this:

[wiki objectify v5 queries on embedded class](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries#indexing-embedded-classes)

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a space between indexed-property-name and '='. Try this: `filter("position.address.city =", aCity)`

Comment: I tried it, but nothing is changed. I also try to get information about city directly from Position class, adding city as her member variable, and it works. But why doesn't it work with a second level Embedded Class?

Comment: You definitely need the space. As to why it doesn't work, perhaps you saved the entity and _then_ added the @Index annotation? Resave the entity.